# Criar uma tela dinâmica em Java

Tags: java, swing, javafx

Criei um software em Java para fazer comparações, a ideia é cadastrar objetos como celulares e criar critérios para definir o melhor de acordo com seu peso.

Problema:
Quero cadastrar uma quantidade ilimitada de celular e critérios, estou tentando criar uma tabela dinâmica que as linhas são produtos e colunas critérios sem ter um tamanho fixo.

**Tela:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Logica:**
Tentei desenvolver um for que vai até a quantidade de itens e para cada item era adicionado a Label produtos e um caixa de texto para colocar o peso de cada critério mas sem sucesso.